# Assigning an integer to a char array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, char

I tried inserting integers into a char array and failed, for some reason when I assign a value (for example  `charc[0] = 2`) I get this weird value of '50', and when I tried debugging I noticed there are actually 2 values for each cell in the array, for example when I assigned `charc[0] = 2` it showed me 2 different values: "50,'2'").
Therefore I when I try and access the value in each cell I get the 50 (Which I read is the ASCII value) instead of the desirable 2.
The "line" variable contains a string in this format: "`23x11x5`" (3 seperate nubmers with a "x" between them). This is the code:

```
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TextFilePathHere.txt");
           line = sr.ReadLine();
           char[] charc = new char[line.Length];
                charc = line.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: '2' corresponds to ASCII value `50`. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/1280px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png

Comment: `I get this weird value of '50'` it's a character code. Try `charc[0] = '2'` or `charc[0] = 2.ToString()[0]` or better `charc[0] = 2 + 48` where 48 is constant for every decimal digit as it's an index of `0` in character table.

Comment: Back conversion `int number = int.Parse(charc[0].ToString())` or simply `int number = charc[0] - 48`.

Comment: I use the function `ToCharArray()` which assigns both ASCII and desired values, you're basically saying I have to assign each integer individually and not use said function?

Comment: To parse `"23x11x5"` use `int[] numbers = line.Split('x').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()`, and you'll get an array of 3 numbers. Back conversion `string text = string.Join("x", numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()))`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `charc[0] = 2`, haven't you got the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'`? You can't assign a integer to a char type field.

Try to assign it like `charc[0] = '2'` or `charc[0] = 2.ToString()[0];`.

Besides, the first character of "23x11x5" is '2', so the line will not change. You also said "tried inserting integers". So if want to insert a char, you can call [`String.Insert(Int32, String) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=net-5.0).

```
string newString = line.Insert(0, "9");
Console.WriteLine(newString); // 923x11x5
```

Since the size of the array is fixed, try to use List which you can add char dynamically.

```
List<char> list = line.ToCharArray().ToList();
list.Insert(0, '9');
Console.WriteLine(new string(list.ToArray()));
```